# Is opening new tab equivalent to opening new window?

Tags: terminal, performance, gnome-terminal, terminal-multiplexer, multiprocessor

Is opening new tab in the terminal window is equivalent to opening a new tab in terms of resources? I need to run 16 scripts in parallel. I do not know whether opening tabs or new terminals is the best practice? I want to get the maximum performance but without exhausting the resources to an extent that degrades the performance.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it is close the same. I cannot judge if opening more windows with terminal take more resources than one window with more tabs, but the window object take CPU time only while changing. You can test the performance with command `cp /dev/zero /dev/null` what takes 100% of one core (this is a simple load test). Run more such commands in more terminals and look at `top` or KSysGuard to see the result. I hope you have at least 16 cores for that.

Comment: I have `Intel® Core™ i5-6500 CPU @ 3.20GHz × 4`. does this seems sufficient?

Comment: I am not familiar with Intel nicks, but suoppose that i5 has 4 cores, and you have four CPU: together 16cores could be sufficient. I do not know how complex is your script, but if one script take full load of one core it is good idea to support each instance with one core. In the same way you need to look for other component: if the script intensively read from the disk, 16 scripts could cause crush while reading the same disk. But sometimes it is more important the task was carried out than how quickly it was finished.

Comment: Each script read an address from a text file in a loop. Then connects to the address using TLS connection. I think it is considered a lightweight task.

Answer (score 0):

No. E.g. in Gome terminal (and others, like firefox or emacs) a new *tab* is added to the current window (and you can switch among them); a new *window* is separate. Often you can tear out a tab into it's separate window (but not the other way around, curiously).